# Define horizontally strechable drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would like to define a background drawable roughtly as illustrated here:

[image: Regions]

The green regions should be scaled so as if this was an ImageView, meaning that the aspect ratio remains constant.
The blue region should be streched if the element is wider than the background image.

I tried to accomplish this with 9patch images, but those have to be defined with at least one horizontal strechable region. There doesn't seem to be a way to just keep the aspect ratio of the green regions.

Comment: Make your own `Drawable` that draws the green parts at their basic dimensions followed by a middle ninepatch(blue area).

Comment: Can that be defined in XML? If yes, how would such a definition look like?

Comment: As a xml no, you need to make your own custom Drawable class. You could use a `layer-list` but that would still require you to change in code the insets at which you draw the three drawables(and I don't know how well would that go when the view would change it's bounds).